# Saving mail content in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am creating Email sending functionality.
This functionality devided into two services.
Service-1: Prepare email content and save conetnt to Cassandra table.
Service-2: Pick email content from Cassandra and send Email to user.

My question is: is Cassandra is good Database to store email content or i need to use diff Database?

Answer (score 2):

Efficiently it's a queue pattern, that is generally [anti-pattern for Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-datasets).  Primarily, because you need to know partition from which to read, this will lead to tombstones, etc.

For this kind of work, I would select something like Kafka, or other messaging system.

Comment: I have generated UUID in my code and i have mailerId.
So i can use mailerId as partition key?

Comment: Yes, but if you have only few mailer IDs, then it will lead to skewed workload